event->id->qp is NULL on rdma server and client
I'm trying to run a simple hello world RDMA example.  The client seems to connect, but I'm getting an segmentation fault on the server because event->id->qp is NULL.
Both client and server are running inside privileged docker containers on the same host.  The docker host is itself a Linux VM running aarch64 on Mac OS (Apple Silicon, M3).
Soft-RoCE is installed and configured on the Linux docker host and the docker containers.
    while (rdma_get_cm_event(ec, &event) == 0) {
        if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_CONNECT_REQUEST) {
            pd = rc_get_pd(event->id);
            if (!pd) {
                perror("rc_get_pd");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            mr = rc_get_reg_mr(pd, msg, MSG_SIZE);
            if (!mr) {
                perror("rc_get_reg_mr");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            sge = rc_get_sge(mr);
            if (!sge) {
                perror("rc_get_sge");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            recv_wr = rc_get_recv_wr(sge);
            if (!recv_wr) {
                perror("rc_get_recv_wr");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (!event->id) {
                printf("Event ID is NULL\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            printf("Queue Pair Type: %p\n",event->id->qp_type); // 0x2

            if (!event->id->qp) {
                printf("Queue pair is NULL\n");

                // CODE IS FAILING HERE
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

on the client:
       ... } else if (event->event == RDMA_CM_EVENT_ROUTE_RESOLVED) {
            printf("Route resolved.\n");
            conn_param.initiator_depth = 1;
            conn_param.retry_count = 7;

            printf("Accepting connection...\n");
            if (rdma_connect(event->id, &conn_param)) {
                perror("rdma_connect");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Connection established.\n");

            if (!event->id->qp) {
                printf("Queue pair is NULL\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Queue pair: %p\n", event->id->qp);

Client outputs:
Route resolved.
Accepting connection...
Connection established.
Queue pair is NULL

Any thoughts?

Not familar with soft-roce, but have you create the qp?
